# How to use parameters for cocos2d schedule: function

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, selector

How to use parameters for schedule function

```
 [self schedule:@selector(cloudMovement:cloud1) interval:1/30];

-(void)cloudMovement:(CCSprite*)cloud
{
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

  if (cloud.position.x == size.width )
  {
    [cloud setPosition:ccp(0,size.height-100)];
    [cloud runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:20 position:ccp(size.width,size.height-100)]];
  }
}
```

Comment: scheduleSelector only allows ccTime as parameter, use performSelector instead or CCCallFunc action

Comment: Me either don't want to use `performSelector`, since `schedule` is the only one of them you can pause.